# iOS: Javascript code in WKWebView got “query cancelled” error after selecting photo from photo library and before uploading to the server

Tags: javascript, ios, html, uiwebview, wkwebview

I use Xcode 9.1(9B55), iOS 11.1 both simulator and real iPhone/iPad.

The website(HTML5+Javascript) I used in mobile safari acts perfectly. But in my iOS app(Objective-C), which uses WKWebView to access the same web page, and set all the "privacy - Photo Library Usage" and others, always got the error below after selecting photo from photo library and before uploading to the server:

[discovery] errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}

But something strange was that I had a successful run for just one time.

I've several threads about this issue, but have no clear solution. Someone said it's a bug of iOS 11.x, but I've tried it on iOS 9.x, the error was same.

Comment: Having the same problem.   I've seen a couple people say that doing a override func dismiss... call to close the vc .  But thats not working for me in latest Xcode and iOS.  (same version as you describe above)

Comment: @topget Have you found solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on iOS 12.1. I spent a lot of time trying to figure out why I'm getting this error. I thought because of that error I can't upload an image to the server. But turned out on each try, the request **fails** with 401 status code because of permissions or additional http headers/cookies. In my case, this debug error meant nothing I thought(Maybe that's why additional argument **OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disabled** in project scheme worked for other guys, because it just removed debug log from console). So, make sure you have a correct HTTP request with all permissions/headers as well. Maybe it will help you as It helped me. Good luck.